# P3P checking for sites

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cookies

I try to understand the P3P policy which Internet Explorer uses.

I found this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/389458

Also I use this validator to check sites:
http://p3pvalidatortool.com/

For a site the validator shows me that the site is valid, but when I go to the source code, I can see the p3p header or in server calls I can't find it!

Also in IE11 how is it possible to have the eye icon in the progress bar like the link answer?

Comment: Example this site http://doubleclickadvertisers.blogspot.gr/ if we use the pep3validatortool.com says that it has not a P3P header. As result it shouldn't execute third party cookies. However if we open the link in IE11 and use the developer tools in Network -> Details -> Request header for hearder https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js we have data. The must blocked.

Comment: FYI: p3p is only relevant to IE on Windows 8.1 or less. Microsoft Edge and IE11 on Windows 10 do not support p3p - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx